# How to resolve conflicting Path.class between jsr311-api and jersey-core?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am working with both jersey-core:1.8 and jrs311:0.8. Both dependencies are needed. When running the unit test IntellJ, sometimes I get the exception below. Arranging the order of the dependencies stopped the exception however when starting up in Tomcat 7.0.2, the exception always appears. Rearranging the libs does not resolve the issue.

Digging into it further, I found the class "javax.ws.rs.Path" is in both dependencies. It has been included but not as a dependency. The one in jrs311 contains an extra method called **limited()**. The class **URITemplate** seems to be always finding the Path.class in the **jersey-core** lib hence the exception.

I have tried switching to different versions of the libraries but unsuccessful. Due to the code I am working with both libraries are needed.

Anyone has any ideas on how to resolve such issue?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean com.emailvision.nsapi.conf.NsApiSpringConf.restServerFactory(com.emailvision.nsapi.service.impl.NotificationServiceREST)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.Path.limited()Z
 * at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
 * at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
 * ... 27 more
 * Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.Path.limited()Z
 * at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.URITemplate.createTemplate(URITemplate.java:167)
 * at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.createClassResourceInfo(JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.java:198)
 * at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.setResourceClassesFromBeans(JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.java:139)
 * at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setServiceBeans(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:272)
```

Comment: If this is your only problem you can copy the class from jsr311 jar to the jersey-core jar and see it it will work.

Comment: This wont work as these dependencies are managed by Maven. Sure removed one the of Path.class will work but whenever I do a rebuild the dependency get overridden? It needs to have some sort of control to prevent another member of my team from replacing it.

Comment: You can create your own version and then, deploy it to your team repository if you have one or add it to git or whatever VCS you are using. Start buy checking if it will actually solve your problem.

Comment: @Oleg - this works however I was looking for more of a robus solution?

Comment: As long as you keep the same jars and it really does solve all the problems it's robust. There is no good solution to [jar hell](https://blog.codefx.org/java/jar-hell/), you're lucky that you were able to solve it in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution which works in a predictable manner. What I did was download the source for `javax.ws.rs.Path` from the `jrs311:0.8` dependency which contains the `limited()` method. I then added to my src as part of my project. Since the SRC of my project has a higher precedency than any dependencies, Java always pick up this class.

I do not like the solution myself. I had to write a big report to judstify my action to my boss. Thinking about it more, the guys that package the `jrs311:0.8` jar must have had the same issue as why would you include an open-source java code that you didn't write yourself.

Comment: The above solution didn't work for all cenarios. Code that initalise jrs311 classes works but code that uses jersey-core failed. In the end, I had to remove jersey-core and reimplement using jackson instead. Hopes this help those whos looking for solution.